# Optimize logistic calculator python

Tags: python

I just started to learn python and I have the project to build a Distance calculator for logistic purpose.
So the main code ask to enter a number of palets and the distance in km.
And then the first 150 km are multiply by 2 for the price.
The next 150km (until 300km then) are multiply by 1.8. (The first 150 km are added so 300 $)
And finally, above 300 km, we multiply by 1.6.

But we have an other subtlety, we have a palet coefficient that are multiply and it changes with the km just like the price coef.

So I let you see my current code which is a little big but I can't find a way to optimize it.
I've separate the code in 2 files, "Function" and "main".

Here is it :

Function :

```
`
def calcul150(pal, distance):
    if distance > 150:
        prix = 300
    else:
        prix = float(distance * 2)
    if pal <= 4:
        prix = prix * 0.4
    elif pal <= 8:
        prix = prix * 0.5
    elif pal <= 12:
        prix = prix * 0.6
    elif pal <= 16:
        prix = prix * 0.7
    elif pal <= 20:
        prix = prix * 0.8
    elif pal <= 24:
        prix = prix * 0.85
    elif pal <= 28:
        prix = prix * 0.9
    print(prix)
    return prix

def calcul300(pal, distance):
    prix = calcul150(pal, distance)
    if distance > 300:
        distance = 300
    if pal <= 4:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.3
    elif pal <= 8:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.4
    elif pal <= 12:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.5
    elif pal <= 16:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.6
    elif pal <= 20:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.7
    elif pal <= 24:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.75
    elif pal <= 28:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * 0.8
    else:
        prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8
    print(prix)
    return prix

def calculLD(pal, distance):

    prix = calcul300(pal, distance)
    if pal <= 4:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.2
    elif pal <= 8:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.3
    elif pal <= 12:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.4
    elif pal <= 16:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.5
    elif pal <= 20:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.6
    elif pal <= 24:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.65
    elif pal <= 28:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * 0.7
    else:
        prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6
    print(prix)
    return prix

`
```

and the Main :

```
from function import *
pal = int(input("How many palets ? "))
distance = float(input("Distance ? "))
prix = float(0.0)
i = int(0)

if distance <= 150:
    prix = calcul150(pal, distance)
elif distance <= 300:
    prix = calcul300(pal, distance)
else:
    prix = calculLD(pal, distance)

print("price is {} dollars" .format(prix))

input("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your palets thresholds according to their prix multiplying value in `dict` and then look for smallest key of that dict that's higher than `pal` and then use its value to multiply prix.

```
def calcul150(pal, distance):
    if distance > 150:
        prix = 300
    else:
        prix = float(distance * 2)

    multipliers = {4: 0.4, 8: 0.5, 12: 0.6, 16: 0.7, 20: 0.85, 24: 0.85, 28: 0.9}
    multiplier = [multipliers[i] for i in sorted(multipliers) if pal <= i]
    if not multiplier:
        multiplier = [1]

    prix *= multiplier[0]
    print(prix)
    return prix

def calcul300(pal, distance):
    prix = calcul150(pal, distance)

    if distance > 300:
        distance = 300

    multipliers = {4: 0.3, 8: 0.4, 12: 0.5, 16: 0.6, 20: 0.7, 24: 0.75, 28: 0.8}
    multiplier = [multipliers[i] for i in sorted(multipliers) if pal <= i]
    if not multiplier:
        multiplier = [1]

    prix = prix + (distance-150) * 1.8 * multiplier[0]
    print(prix)
    return prix

def calculLD(pal, distance):
    prix = calcul300(pal, distance)

    multipliers = {4: 0.2, 8: 0.3, 12: 0.4, 16: 0.5, 20: 0.6, 24: 0.65, 28: 0.7}
    multiplier = [multipliers[i] for i in sorted(multipliers) if pal <= i]
    if not multiplier:
        multiplier = [1]

    prix = prix + (distance-300) * 1.6 * multiplier[0]
    print(prix)
    return prix
```

And for Main part you don't need to convert `0` to `int` and `0.0` to `float` you could just initiate those values

```
pal = int(input("How many palets ? "))
distance = float(input("Distance ? "))
prix = 0.0
i = 0

if distance <= 150:
    prix = calcul150(pal, distance)
elif distance <= 300:
    prix = calcul300(pal, distance)
else:
    prix = calculLD(pal, distance)

print("price is {} dollars" .format(prix))

input("")
```

Output:

```
How many palets ? 28
Distance ? 300
270.0
486.0
price is 486.0 dollars
```

Comment: Man, that's awesome ! I'm trying to understand what you have done with the dict I can't figure it out, it's a great approach because you use a lot of thing I don't master yet. I will study your method and try to understand, thank you a lot !

Comment: To help you understand here's simple explanation. `multipliers` is a dict which keys(palets) correspond to multipliers. First we find all multipliers where amount of palets is higher than palets supplied by user and then we pick smallest one (`multiplier[0]`). If number of palets is higher than any of our keys (`multiplier` is empty list) we manualy choose multiplier to be 1 (`multiplier = [1]`).